# malformed unicode / hexadecimal in php

Tags: php, javascript, utf-8, escaping

I want to give a text to a DIV. This text has HTML tags, so I thought its enough to escape the " and ' characters. Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lay">.</div>
<?php
 $a = 'Missing<hr />argument 3 for Class::method(), called in X:\directory\dir2\dir3\x';
 $a = str_replace(array("\"", "'"), array("&quot;", '&#039;'), $a);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('lay').innerHTML = '<?php echo $a; ?>';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but firefox said its malformed. Even htmlspecialchars() aint work. How the heck to escape this string? And why it fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `addslashes` like so:

```
 $a = 'Missing<hr />argument 3 for Class::method(), called in X:\directory\dir2\dir3\x';
 $a = addslashes($a);
 $a = str_replace(array("\"", "'"), array("&quot;", '&#039;'), $a);
```

As [the documentation says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php):

> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be
>   quoted in database queries etc. These characters are single quote ('),
>   double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).

Comment: oh, then it protects from everything? No other things (binary, unicode, anything) to escape from?

Answer (score 1):

the "\x" at the end of you string is now trying to expect a hexadecimal digit you need to escape the slash in front of the x.

try adding three slashes

`$a = 'Missing<hr />argument 3 for Class::method(), called in X:\directory\dir2\dir3\\\x';`

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this.
I was displaying image using physical path in browser:
"D:/wamp/www/project/images/imag.png"

-> malformed Unicode character escape sequence

I set it to URL then it resolved my problem
"http://siteurl/images/imag.png"